# Consultar disponibilidad entre hora de inicio y hora final en mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy realizando una asignación de citaciones donde hay una fecha, una hora de inicio y hora final de la citación.
Al ingresar una hora de inicio y hora final primero debo validar si hay disponibilidad entre esas horas, Estoy intentado de varias maneras con
`between , >= and <=`, Si esta hora 08:00 y 10:00 esta ocupada no me debe dejar asignar entre 08:30 y 09:30 o entre 09:30 y 10:30, al contrario si deja asignar. Me podrían por favor ayudar con esto muchas gracias. 
Intente de estas maneras pero no valida bien

```
SELECT Sl_idSala , Sl_FechaInicio, Sl_FechaFinal ,Sl_HoraInicio, Sl_HoraFin FROM sala
WHERE Sl_FechaInicio = '2020-01-24' AND Sl_FechaFinal = '2020-01-24'
AND Sl_HoraInicio >= '08:00:00' AND Sl_HoraFin <= '10:00:00'

/*********************/

SELECT Sl_idSala , Sl_FechaInicio, Sl_FechaFinal ,Sl_HoraInicio, Sl_HoraFin FROM sala
WHERE Sl_FechaInicio = '2020-01-24' AND Sl_FechaFinal = '2020-01-24'
AND Sl_HoraInicio BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND Sl_Horafin
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir un dataset de ejemplo a tu pregunta? Y el resultado esperado para esos datos..

Comment: @Angelita, Creo que aquí, lo importante es conocer el tipo de datos de las columnas `Sl_FechaInicio` , `Sl_HoraInicio` y las de fin. Si nos cuentas la definición de la tabla, al menos de estos campos podremos ayudarte

Comment: @Roger Las fechas están en tipo Date y las horas están en tipo Time